# set a variable with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to set a variable with the following function setDef().

My example do not work. What I have to do?

```
    var defs = {
      title: document.title,
      action:   "pageview"
    };

    var setDefs = function(a,b) {
       defs.a= b;     // this: defs.title = b; is working.
    };

    setDefs("title","test");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bracket notation, `object[variable]`, instead:

```
var setDefs = function(a,b) {
       defs[a] = b;
};
```

Also it would be better suited to include this method in the object:

```
var defs = {
      title: document.title,
      action:   "pageview",
      setDefs: function(a,b) {
       this[a] = b; 
      }
};

defs.setDefs("title","test");

// > defs
// Object {title: "test", action: "pageview", setDefs: function}
```

Comment: thx for your hint, good idea. but if I include it, I can't change an exsisting variabale.

Comment: @hamburger, what do you mean? with your original code it can only add properties to the defs object.

Comment: setDefs("title","test"); will overwrite the origin property of the defs object. But if I think about your proposal to include setDefs in the object, it will do the same.